# SQL current order and receive information

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, one is the order_info table (id, order), another one is receive_info table (id, receive), and sometimes I received more orders, sometimes I received fewer orders, and I want to use SQL code to create an output table containing the current order and receiving status.

**order_info**

| id | order |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 |

**receive_info**

| id | receive |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

**output**

| id | order | receive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 |

```
For example,
For Id 1, we ordered 5 and 3 items, and we received 5 and 3 items.
For Id 2, we ordered 8 items, and we only received 5 items.
For Id 3, we ordered 2 items, but we received 1 and 3 items which are a total of 4 items.
For Id 4, we ordered 5 items, and we didn't receive any items, so it is 0.

create table order_info (
  id integer,
  order_quantity integer
);
insert into order_info values (1,5),(1,3),(2,8),(3,2),(4,5);

create table receive_info (
  id integer,
  receive_quantity integer
);
insert into receive_info values (1,5),(1,3),(2,5),(3,1),(3,3);
```

Comment: You should explain your output OP. Where does (3, 2, 4) come from in the output?

Comment: define `current status` in your design.

Comment: What determines that order #1 first ordered 5 and received 5? It could just as easily be that it first "ordered 5 but received **3**", and then "ordered 3, but received **5**".  Seems like some relationship is missing in the schema ...